# Prove that $x$ is in $W$ if and only if $\operatorname{proj}_{W(x)} = x$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Exactly the same problem as: [Prove that x is in W if and only if $proj_W$(x) = x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006495/prove-that-x-is-in-w-if-and-only-if-proj-wx-x)

I was wondering if it is enough to say that if $x$ is in $W$ then $\operatorname{perp}_{W(x)} = 0$. Since:
$ x = \operatorname{perp}_{W(x)} + \operatorname{proj}_{W(x)}$, thus $x = \operatorname{proj}_{W(x)}$

If not, can someone explain me this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1006503/316772 in more detail. How do I go about to prove that:

1. $\operatorname{proj}_{W} (\mathbb{R}^n) = W$
2. $\operatorname{proj}_{W(x)}|_W = \operatorname{id}_W$.

And what does $\operatorname{proj}_{W}|_W$ and $\operatorname{id}_W$ mean?

Comment: Ad (1): If $x\in proj_W(\mathbb R^n)$, then $x = proj_W(y)$ for some $y$. So, as $proj_W$ maps into $W$, $x\in W$. Conversely, if $x\in W$ then $proj_W(x) = x$ and so $x\in proj_W(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: Ad (2): $proj_W|_W$ denotes the restriction of $proj_W$ to $W$.